What is the big blue circular thing on the Blue Ring "Space Truck"?


An illustration of Blue Ring in orbit. Illustration: Blue Origin (I've added a zoom of the "big blue thing" area.)

Gizmodo's September 9, 2024 NASA Postpones Upcoming Mars Mission, Citing Delays With Bezos’s Big Rocket says:

Now that the Mars mission is off the table for New Glenn’s inaugural launch, the company will instead carry a type of technology for its Blue Ring orbital platform.

which links to their March 20, 2024 Pentagon Mission Will Include Test of Blue Origin’s ‘Space Truck’ which contains the image above.
In it I see what looks like Hall effect thrusters (the little "blue rings") above, below and inside? the big blue central structure, which I'm guessing is concave and blue inside?  In the center there's what looks like a nozzle.
Question What is the big blue circular thing on the Blue Ring "Space Truck"?

It looks less blue in this image from their website https://d3ezn0y6hdgq62.cloudfront.net/assets/photos/blue-ring/blue-ring-spacecraft.jpeg

It's a photoshop artifact!

I'm guessing the three glowy blue things are the electric thrusters. No idea why the aft end of the spacecraft is a big cone.

There's something inside that cone which looks like a conventional thruster (cold gas or chemical), and then there's the ion thruster splattered into the cone, off-axis. Are we sure this is not just a slip of the mouse in Blender? :-D

@OrganicMarble That would probably make the blueness come from it reflecting something in space/the ocean/the sky/the electric engine or something like that (which I think is possible).
